# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS asks for password and login before installing

Tags: system-installation, login, password

During Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS installation, it ask me to write login and than password in the beginning.

[image]

What password and login I should write?

Comment: Where did you get the installation iso from?

Answer (score 1):

During the install of a new Linux machine, you need to provide your-user-name (e.g. `maxim`) and your favorite password (*what-ever-you-like*).

You'll need to remember the username/password as you'll use them when you'll log-into the computer, and will install software...etc.

[tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#9)

> 10. Login details
>
> Enter your name and the installer will automatically suggest a
>   computer name and username. These can easily be changed if you prefer.
>   The computer name is how your computer will appear on the network,
>   while your username will be your login and account name.
>
> Next, enter a strong password. The installer will let you know if it's
>   too weak.
>
> You can also choose to enable automatic login and home folder
>   encryption. If your machine is portable, we recommend keeping
>   automatic login disabled and enabling encryption. This should stop
>   people accessing your personal files if the machine is lost or stolen.
>
> [image]
>
> If enable home folder encryption and you forget your password, you
>   won't be able to retrieve any personal data stored in your home
>   folder.

Comment: No, I haven't installing block, just when I press "install ubuntu" I have something like that: http://cdn.itzgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Upgrade-to-Ubuntu-16.04-from-Ubuntu-14.04-Ubuntu-16.04-Login-Screen.png